# Dynamic Data: Scaffolds are read-only for LINQ classes using Views instead of Tables?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I am trying to use the ASP.NET Dynamic Data features to generate CRUD scaffolding for my data model. My model contains supertype/subtype relationships, so some logical entities are split between two tables: one for the generic data and one for the subtype-specific data.

In the LINQ context I expose these entities as a single class, backed by a view that joins the tables together. I have also created sprocs for insert/update/delete and configured the class behaviour to use them.

When I turn on scaffolding, it only generates a read-only view of this data. The add, edit and remove links don't show up. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was that I did not identify a Primary Key column on the LINQ classes after dragging the views onto the surface. After adding a PK the CRUD functions showed up.